# Javascript Date to C# Sortable ("s") Format

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass DateTime as string to my Web API service and parsing it to sortable datetime in c#. Please find the code below:

```
public static DateTime? ToDateTime(this string dateTime)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTime))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, Constant.DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Client side code:

```
var d = new Date();
var dateTime = JSON.stringify(d); // e.x: "2014-01-01T23:28:56.782Z"
```

I tried below options as well:

```
d.toLocaleDateString()); 
d.toLocaleString();
d.toDateString();
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you're just trying to take it form a JavaScript Date object to a C# DateTime? object, why do you need it to be in the Sortable string format in between?

Comment: Keep in mind you also need to account for the GMT offset of the local client as well.

Comment: @Tim Because that is an existing support format in the code, I cannot afford to change it now, and deal with the ripple effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you insist passing it as a string so you could use momentjs

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

and than you could parse it with format on the server side

You did not provide you web api code
but another approach would be to change the serializer for Datetime on the server side

```
// class to be serialized
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime? DateTime1;
    public DateTime? DateTime2;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use momentjs in this scenario. Is there a way to use plain javascript to do this?

Comment: of course d.getFullYear()+" "+d.getMonth()+" "+d.getDate(), but I think in that case the server side changing of the serializer would be better, especially if the case is in various places

Comment: in that case the best solution would be to inherit from your whole object with subclass and to write a JsonCreationConverter for it I guess. There you could put the condition on how to parse it in the case it comes in null. or you could on the client side test if it is null and than just delete the property from an object - I do this when I do not have control over server side